# Build Alexa Auto SDK on Apple Silicon

Tags: build, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-auto-sdk

I try to build Alexa Auto SDK https://github.com/alexa/alexa-auto-sdk/blob/3.2/builder/README.md

and I use an Apple Silicon M1, installed Docker successfully but

sadly I run now with

`./builder/build.sh android -t androidx86-64 --android-api 28`

into

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.36.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "aarch64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-16.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "x86_64-linux-android"
MACHINE              = "androidx86-64"
DISTRO               = "aac"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.2.0"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m64 core2"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta-aac-ubuntu      = "GithubActionDocker:d95957b17c830989e17cb92440bfbda90135e051"
meta                 = "HEAD:1b18cdf6b8bdb00ff5df165b9ac7bc2b10c87d57"
meta-aac             
meta-aac-builder     = "GithubActionDocker:d95957b17c830989e17cb92440bfbda90135e051"

Initialising tasks: 100% |############################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:02
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: zlib-native-1.0-r0 do_install: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /workdir/build/tmp-android-28/work/aarch64-linux/zlib-native/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.4431)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /workdir/build/tmp-android-28/work/aarch64-linux/zlib-native/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.4431
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| cp: cannot stat '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.*': No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /workdir/build/tmp-android-28/work/aarch64-linux/zlib-native/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.4431)
ERROR: Task (/home/builder/aac/builder/meta-aac-ubuntu/recipes-native/zlib/zlib-native.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 67 tasks of which 0 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/builder/aac/builder/meta-aac-ubuntu/recipes-native/zlib/zlib-native.bb:do_install
```

Has someone an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: any detailed doc at `/workdir/build/tmp-android-28/work/aarch64-linux/zlib-native/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.4431` ?

Comment: @lescaudr Sorry, this file does not exist, But assume the significant content is posted here. This found nothing find ~ -name "*log.do_install*" 2>/dev/null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but I was facing a similar issue building the auto-sdk for android on MAC OS machines (intel based silicon)
We were able to solve the problem by increasing the docker default ram usage (set to 2gb).
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/
After increasing to 6gb it worked perfectly.